# bcp utility with Visual C#

Tags: c#, bcp

I try to use SQL Server `bcp` utility in Visual C# like this:

```
command = new SqlCommand ("bcp "+ onlineConnect.Database+".dbo.T1 out "+ ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["caleonline"]+"T1.dat -n -S " + onlineConnect.DataSource+" -U sa -P a" ,onlineConnect );
```

When I run it with breakpoints I get this:

```
CommandText 
"bcp ONLINE.dbo.T1 out H:\\ONLINE\\fisiere\\T1.dat -n -S ATTY\\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P a"
```

but I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled Message=Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the file path with quotation marks?

Comment: Calling `bcp`  is **not** a SQL statement, therefore you cannot use `SqlCommand` for this. Just call the `bcp` utilty as an *external program* (using `Process.Start` or something like that)

Comment: You are right, works fine with Process.Start

Answer (score 1):

Prefix the command with `exec xp_cmdShell`

```
command=new SqlCommand ("exec xp_cmdShell 'bcp.exe'"+ onlineConnect.Database+".dbo.T1 out "+ ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["caleonline"]+"T1.dat -n -S " + onlineConnect.DataSource+" -U sa -P a" ,onlineConnect );
```